# How do I connect laptop to TV?

Tags: tv

When I connect my laptop to TV via HDMI it shows me this:

[image]

but it shows me it the screens one on the another and sometimes I don’t see windows, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

## Duplicate the displays

Sounds to me that when you launch a window, it is opening either on your main laptop display or on the TV. If you want to see exactly what you open up and have it display on both screen exactly, then go into your display settings:

- Click on `Built-in Display`
- Then to your right, tick off the box that says `Mirror displays`.
- Finally, click the button that says `Apply`

This should end your confusion, as what you see on one display, you will see on both.

Here is a visual:

[image]

### Note:

Your resolution will depend on how powerful your laptop graphics card is. So if your resolution looks funny, you can adjust in the same area, `Display`. The maximum resolution will depend on the quality of your graphics card.